# How to force kill Picture and Picture activity on cross icon click?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-task, picture-in-picture, android-picture-in-picture

i am trying to kill activity from tasks after picture and picture mode was activated and so far I tried `finish()`, `finishAffinity()`, `onBackPressed()`, programmatically set `excludeFromRecent` but activity still lives on in background..

We can see same behavior in `Google Maps` when we click on that cross icon. App still lives in background, but i need to brutally kill it :)

```
    <activity
        android:name=".PipActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
        android:resizeableActivity="true"
        android:taskAffinity=".PipAffinity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"/>
```

This is how i fire intent:

```
        Intent(context, PipActivity::class.java)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK))
```

**Important note**: when this activity is not going to `PiP mode` everything works as expected and activity kills itself normally when i need it!

when i click o this cross icon:

[image]

onStop in pipActivity gets called:

```
override fun onStop() {
        cleanView()
        finish()
        finishAffinity()
        setExcludeRecentToKillActivity()
}

private fun setExcludeRecentToKillActivity() {
    val am = getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
    val tasks = am.appTasks
    if (tasks != null && tasks.size > 0) {
        tasks[0].setExcludeFromRecents(true)
    }
}
```

At this point UI is cleaned and connection interrupted. But System still holds task in background and when i click on it it restarts itself.

I dont want this. The task on right is that closed PiP activity that should not be alive. I want to kill it. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So actually i found the solution. `finish()` have to be changed for `finishAndRemoveTask()` and task will be closed in background correctly. So `setExcludeRecentToKillActivity()` is not needed anymore.

```
override fun onStop() {
   cleanView()
   finishAndRemoveTask()
   finishAffinity()
}
```